# FPDF issue while generating pdf with images due to PHP 'allow_url_fopen' setting

Tags: php, fpdf

I am facing a problem with FPDF while generating the PDF file with images as explained `here`. Finally I found the reason for this issue but I am not sure how to fix that one, can anybody suggest some good solution to handle that issue.

This problem is due to the `allow_url_fopen` setting of my server, if I enable that setting then the FPDF library is generating the PDF file with images also without any errors.

I am using this FPDF library for one of my client sites, he(client) disabled the 'allow_url_fopen' setting for security reasons and he is not intersted to enable that setting. how can I solve this issue with out enabling that setting of my server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177716/fpdf-error-missing-or-incorrect-image-file/66607028#66607028   try this for some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURL  to open remote resources.

```
$curlHandler=curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://youurl.com");

curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output =curl_exec($curlHandler);

....

curl_close($curlHandler);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks Luis Melgratti, CURL may do the trick to handle this issue. I am planing to get the image using CURL and store that in a temporary file before adding that image to PDF file using FPDF.

Comment: Yes Luis Melgratti, I've used the CURL to fix this issue. To solve my problem I'm creating a temporary file in my local system using the CURL and sending that local file path to the FPDF function. Even your code snippet is not useful exactly for fixing this issue, I got an idea to solve my problem after seeing your answer. Once again thanks for your response...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, the fix for it without setting allow_url_fopen on was
1. move the image to the server hosting the script
2. assume the image is imagefile.gif inside a folder called images
3. access the image in my script doing this  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."images/imagesfile.gif"

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you for posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your best bet is going to finding another way to generate PDFs.  FPDF has had [only one update since 2004](http://www.fpdf.org/en/histo.php), and no longer seems to be actively maintained.

Some other pure-PHP options include [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) and [Zend_PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html), both of which seem to be actively maintained and supported.

You should also give some consideration to other PDF generation techniques.  For example, there are quite a few [HTML-to-PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters) converters, some commercial, some open source.  [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), for example, uses the WebKit rendering engine (the one that Safari and Chrome use) to create PDFs.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I am also thinking to use some other PDF generator instead of FPDF library, but my client preferred to use the FPDF. Anyway I will try to convence him(client) to go for some other libary, can you please suggest me one good PDF generator so that I can replace the FPDF.

Comment: I recommended no less than three above.  :)

Comment: Furthermore, if your client is both telling you what libraries to use and also telling you what configuration the server must have, despite the library he told you to use *requiring* a different configuration, I expect that you may wish to either educate or stop working with the client.  He or she is probably more trouble than he or she is worth.

Comment: FPDF has been updated many times since 2004. The latest version is v1.84 (2021-08-28)